# IE 8 absolute positioned element outside its parent clipping problem

Tags: internet-explorer-8, filter, overflow, css-position, clipping

I have an absolute positioned div inside another absolute positioned div. The child div content is much bigger than the parent can contain. This is by design. I need the child div to spill out of its parent. It does so in every other browser except IE 8 (IE 7 looks OK, not sure) In IE8 the part of the child that is out of parent is clipped. It is there, but just not visible as can be verified by IE developer tools.
I tried z-index, tried explicitly setting overflow:visible, no luck at all.

UPDATE: I found out that the problem is caused by a filter defined in the parent div like this:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#66C6DEA2,endColorstr=#66C6DEA2)";
```

Anyone has an idea how to work around that?

Comment: this saved me so much headache

Comment: the update was a life saver - this issue was driving me mad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it using this [How do I stop internet explorer's propriety gradient filter from cutting off content that should overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756851/how-do-i-stop-internet-explorers-propriety-gradient-filter-from-cutting-off-cont)

My solution is a little modified, just put an empty div with class "ie_rgba_fix" inside the container you want transparent, add this CSS someplace IE specific and the children will not clip anymore as with overflow: hidden

```
/* IE8 RGB A workaround */
div.ie_rgba_fix
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#66C6DEA2,endColorstr=#66C6DEA2)";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making the elements inside the absolute positioned element `position:relative`, and/or add a wrapper around all the elements in that absolute positioned element and relative it.

Comment: the elements inside the absolute child div are relative. They are two divs with position:relative and with text inside.

Comment: I updated the question, found the cause, but still don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

i took a tip from the checked answer here & the linked question, but didn't want to use an empty DIV (especially because other browsers don't need it).

Instead, i set up IE8-specific CSS that uses the container DIV's `:before` pseudo-element.

However, pseudo-elements are [styled content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10669986/258598), not DOM objects, so the `-ms-filter` property is useless. To compromise, i use a PNG matching the original filter i wanted (actually a `data:` URL, but either works) as the `background-image`.

i force the pseudo-element to the full size of the container, absolute-position it, and *ta-da*, the child element is visible outside the parent, and the parent still gets a transparency background.

```css
.container.ie8 {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}
.container.ie8:before {
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,...");
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```